# How do I install pdftoppm as dependency for textract?

Tags: python, text-extraction, pdftoppm

I am trying to run textract on mac and receive the following error message:

> ShellError: The command `pdftoppm Frome11.pdf /var/folders/h0/7cg0dqzd32gc8wt0j_5wkjsm0000gn/T/tmpplv3r07t/conv` failed because the executable
> `pdftoppm` is not installed on your system. Please make
> sure the appropriate dependencies are installed before using
> textract:

How can I install pdftoppm?

Comment: Well you already know why it's not working.

Comment: As far as I can tell, pdftoppm is part of the poppler package, and if you have installed textract with homebrew, it should have installed it as dependency: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/textract